# Access all href-links in a deep-class hierarchy

Tags: python, selenium, dom, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access all href-links from a website, the search-results to be precise. My first intention is to get all the links, and then to look further on it. The problem is --> I get some links from the website, but not the links of the search-results. Here is one version of my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from htmldom import htmldom
dom = htmldom.HtmlDom("myWebsite")
dom = dom.createDom()

p_links = dom.find("a")
for link in p_links:
    print("URL: " +link.attr("href"))
```

Here is screen of the HTML of that particular website. In the screen, I marked the href-link I try to access in the future. I am open for any help given, be it in Selenium, htmldom, b4soup, etc.

[image]

Comment: @KeyurPotdar https://open.nrw/suche would be the url :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you are after, is loaded with AJAX requests. So, you can't scrape them directly after getting the page source. But, the AJAX request is sent to this URL:

```
https://open.nrw/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&fl=validated_data_dict%20title%20groups%20notes%20maintainer%20metadata_modified%20res_format%20author_email%20name%20extras_opennrw_spatial%20author%20extras_opennrw_groups%20extras_opennrw_format%20license_id&wt=json&fq=-type:harvest+&sort=title_string%20asc&indent=true&rows=20
```

which returns the data in JSON format. You can use `requests` module to scrape this data.

```
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://open.nrw/dataset/'

r = requests.get('https://open.nrw/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&fl=validated_data_dict%20title%20groups%20notes%20maintainer%20metadata_modified%20res_format%20author_email%20name%20extras_opennrw_spatial%20author%20extras_opennrw_groups%20extras_opennrw_format%20license_id&wt=json&fq=-type:harvest+&sort=title_string%20asc&indent=true&rows=20')
data = r.json()
for item in data['response']['docs']:
    print(BASE_URL + item['name'])
```

Output:

```
https://open.nrw/dataset/mags-90-10-dezilsverhaeltnis-der-aequivalenzeinkommen-1512029759099
https://open.nrw/dataset/alkis-nutzungsarten-pro-baublock-wuppertal-w
https://open.nrw/dataset/allgemein-bildende-schulen-am-1510-nach-schulformen-schulen-schueler-und-lehrerbestand-w
https://open.nrw/dataset/altersgruppen-in-meerbusch-gesamt-meerb
https://open.nrw/dataset/amtliche-stadtkarte-wuppertal-raster-w
https://open.nrw/dataset/mais-anteil-abhaengig-erwerbstaetiger-mit-geringfuegiger-beschaeftigung-1477312040433
https://open.nrw/dataset/mags-anteil-der-stillen-reserve-nach-geschlecht-und-altersgruppen-1512033735012
https://open.nrw/dataset/mags-anteil-der-vermoegenslosen-in-nrw-nach-beruflicher-stellung-1512032087083
https://open.nrw/dataset/anzahl-kinderspielplatze-meerb
https://open.nrw/dataset/anzahl-der-sitzungen-von-rat-und-ausschussen-meerb
https://open.nrw/dataset/anzahl-medizinischer-anwendungen-den-oeffentlichen-baedern-duesseldorfs-seit-2006-d
https://open.nrw/dataset/arbeitslose-den-wohnquartieren-duesseldorf-d
https://open.nrw/dataset/arbeitsmarktstatistik-arbeitslose-gelsenkirchen-ge
https://open.nrw/dataset/arbeitsmarktstatistik-arbeitslose-nach-rechtskreisen-des-sgb-ge
https://open.nrw/dataset/arbeitsmarktstatistik-arbeitslose-nach-stadtteilen-gelsenkirchen-ge
https://open.nrw/dataset/arbeitsmarktstatistik-sgb-ii-rechtskreis-auf-stadtteilebene-gelsenkirchen-ge
https://open.nrw/dataset/arbeitsmarktstatistik-sozialversicherungspflichtige-auf-stadtteilebene-gelsenkirchen-ge
https://open.nrw/dataset/verkehrszentrale-arbeitsstellen-in-nordrhein-westfalen-1476688294843
https://open.nrw/dataset/mags-arbeitsvolumen-nach-wirtschaftssektoren-1512025235377
https://open.nrw/dataset/mais-armutsrisikoquoten-nach-geschlecht-und-migrationsstatus-der-personen-1477313317038
```

As you can see, this returned the first 20 URLs. When you first load the page only 20 items are present. But, if you scroll down, more are loaded. To get more items, you can change the *Query String Parameter* in the URL. The URL ends with `rows=20`. You can change this number to get the desired number of results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works like a charm! Do you maybe know some resources, where I could inform myself about how your code specifically works? In order to know, how to do it by myself. How did you do it ? Where did you recognize, that the data is loaded with AJAX-requests?

Comment: Open the Developer tools and go to the XHR tab which is under Network tab. Refresh the page, and you'll see some requests. One of them is to the URL I've used. Click on it, and check the response.

Answer (score 2):

Results appear after the initial page load due to the AJAX request.

I managed to get the links with `Selenium`, however I had to wait for `.ckantitle a` elements to be loaded (these are the links you want to get).

> I should mention that the webdriver will wait for a page to load by
>   default. It does not wait for loading inside frames or for ajax
>   requests. It means when you use .get('url'), your browser will wait
>   until the page is completely loaded and then go to the next command in
>   the code. But when you are posting an ajax request, webdriver does not
>   wait and it's your responsibility to wait an appropriate amount of
>   time for the page or a part of page to load; so there is a module
>   named expected_conditions.

**Code:**

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = 'https://open.nrw/suche'
html = None

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
delay = 3  # seconds

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ckantitle a'))
    )
    html = browser.page_source
except TimeoutException:
    print('Loading took too much time!')
finally:
    browser.quit()

if html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    links = soup.select('.ckantitle a')
    for link in links:
        print(urljoin(url, link['href']))
```

You need to install selenium:

```
pip install selenium
```

and get a driver [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).